# Anyone familiar with the {fei} could help me with the references/bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies

after reading this class manual i found two main commands to be used, the first one being

```
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
```

to add the separate bib file to the document

and the secon one being

```
\printbibliography
```

to print the references in the end of the document

but regardless of how i try it just simply won't work

this is how my Test code looks like

```
\documentclass[rascunho]{fei}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{gensymb}  
\usepackage{cancel}  

\addbibresource{ref.bib}  

\begin{document} 
\begin{center}  
\begin{vplace}  
\begin{HUGE}{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{Fisica Moderna}}}  
\end{HUGE}  
\\  
\vspace{0.2cm}
Material-Base: 
\\  
\vspace{0.2cm} 
R. Eisberg and R. Resnick, Quantum Physics of Atoms, Molecules, Solids, Nuclei, and Particles 2nd Edition, Wiley, 1985 \cite{eisberg1974quantum}.  
\\  
\vspace{0.2cm}
H. Moysés Nussenzveig, Curso de Fisica Basica, 4a. edicao, Vol. 4, Blucher, 2002. \cite{nussenzveig2002curso}  

\end{vplace}  
\end{center}  

\printbibliography  

\end{document}
```

Every time i try to use the F11 command to call bibtex i get the following error message

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit) The top-level
>   auxiliary file: teste.aux I found no \citation commands---while
>   reading file teste.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading
>   file teste.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file
>   teste.aux (There were 3 error messages)
>
> Process exited with error(s)

and i just dont know what else to try to do to fix this, this is how it looks after compiled:

[image: Instead of showind the reference markers it just shows the name in bold...]

my ref.bib file is the following:

```
@book{nussenzveig2002curso,
  title={Curso de f{\'\i}sica b{\'a}sica},
  author={Nussenzveig, Herch Moys{\'e}s},
  year={2002},
  publisher={E. Blucher}
}

@book{eisberg1974quantum,
  title={Quantum physics},
  author={Eisberg, Robert and Resnick, Robert},
  year={1974},
  publisher={John Wiley New York}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try adding `\nocite{*}`.

Comment: You need to run `biber` rather than `bibtex`, but also use some `\cite` (or `\nocite`) command.

Comment: i tried the `\nocite(*)` but i still got the same error @Bernard, but thanks for the warm welcome !

i'm really sorry @egreg but i'm not sure what `biber` is, i use the TexMaker to edit my latex files and i ccouldn't find this option there, how do i do that ?

the \cite command i did use

Comment: Look at the posts listed here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=biber+texmaker

Comment: `biber` is a bibliography  engine, like `bibtex`, but more powerful. In particular it understands `utf8` encoding. You can configure TeXmaker to use it for bibliographies with the menu `Options -> Configure TeXmaker -> Commands tab`, line `Bib(la)tex`.

Comment: would you mind showing me how to do that in the answer ? i just can't seem to  make it work, i went to `Options -> Configure TeXmaker -> Commands tab` and replaced the field `Bib(la)tex` directing it to a file in my computer called Biber that i just downloaded, but now when i try to do the quick build `PdfLatex + Bib(la)tex + PdfLatex(x2) + View Pdf` i just get the message "Process exited with error(s)"
I got my file from [Biber](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Got it ! i was being really stupid, i just had to swap the `bibtex %` for `biber %` and add the Biber file to the same folder as my main tex file, now it works perfectly fine, thank you @Bernard !!